# ColdFusion Administrator page and 408 - Request timeout errors

Tags: coldfusion

I am getting a 408 - Request Timeout error message immediately upon accessing a ColdFusion application.  When I say immediately, this is less than 1 sec.  I don't have access to the ColdFusion Administrator page in my shop.  I am wondering if there is any setting or condition there which would trigger this error?

Comment: When you search your title in Google, did any of the links work?

Comment: Do you have a cfsetting timeout defined ?

Comment: What happened when you presented this problem to the people that do have access to the ColdFusion Administrator page?